# PHPMaker created pages give 403 error

Tags: .htaccess

I created an admin section for a website of mine using PHPMaker - as I usually do. The website is made from scratch, no wordpress or anything else involved.

In some apparently "innocent" tables, if I try to edit them, I get a 403 error. It never happened, and I used PHP maker for at least 15 websites of mine, so I am puzzled.

It happens only on 2 tables out of 15, and as said, they are fairly innocent. Nothing fancy compared to the other ones.

This is what I've tried:

- there was no .htaccess file in the admin directory, so I also tried to insert an empty one
- clearing the cache
- visiting the page in private mode
- all file/directory permissions are ok
- regenerating the project and uploading it again, to a different directory

What else can/should I check?

There is a .htaccess file on the root directory of the server to handle some "pretty url", but it should not matter since the admin section is under a specific directory. Or should it matter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At least, I found the problem: every time I was trying to insert an iframe or a script, somewhere somehow somebody (...) was parsing it and it was blocking it for - I guess - security issues, so I let the user to insert the script without the *<script>* tags, added later in PHP simply with:

```
print "<script>$readFromDB</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In each insert action, PHPMaker will parse the word

```
<script
```

and converted to

```
<s<x>cript
```

You have either get the inserted rowid and update the value again OR each time you have to remove the '< x >' to view the value correctly.

Take a look at my answer here: [PHPMaker issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936502/phpmaker-mysql-issue?answertab=votes#tab-top)